# How to check expected exception using .then synchronous calls in web3js-based Truffle tests?

Tags: web3js, truffle-test

**test.js**

```
var Test=artifacts.require("./Test.sol");

contract('Test', function(accounts) {
    it("test case-1 working", function(){
        var admin_address=accounts[0]; //admin account initialized with 100

        var testit;
        return Test.deployed().then(function(instance){
            testit=instance;
            return testit.balanceOf(admin_address);
        }).then(function(result){
            console.log("admin balance==>",result.valueOf());
            testit.transfer(admin_address,50,{from:admin_address});
            //The error occurs in the line above. How to catch it?
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried both way! still it gave "Uncaught Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert" instead of expected error! @goodvibration

Comment: Refer the following question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30367395/how-to-catch-errors-in-synchronous-functions-in-node-js

Comment: Hi Sunanda! Is that meant as test code, or as main logic for contract interaction from JS? And if it's not test code with Truffle, what's your web3js version?

Comment: it's test code!! @Utgarda

Comment: Well, then using OpenZeppelin helpers is your best shot, check my answer!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

*First I have installed openzeppelin-solidity! after it have import expectThrow.js file in a way given below!! expectThrow.js is available in oppenzeppelin-solidity/test/helpers/expectThrow.js !*

**testit.js**

```
var Test=artifacts.require("./Test.sol");

contract('Test', function(accounts) {
var catcherror=require("../node_modules/openzeppelin-solidity/test/helpers/expectThrow.js").expectThrow;


    it("test case-1 working", function(){
    var admin_address=accounts[0]; //admin account initialized with 100

var testit;
    return Test.deployed().then(function(instance){
    testit=instance;
    return testit.balanceOf(admin_address);
    }).then(function(result){

   console.log("admin balance==>",result.valueOf());
catcherror(transfer(admin_address,50,{from:admin_address}));//here I catched error using expectThrow.js
});

});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to test in JS that your contract throws when it's supposed to, have a look at OpenZeppelin's [helpers](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/tree/master/test/helpers). To check that your contract throws exceptions when it's expected to do so, try `expectThrow`

```
import expectThrow from 'openzeppelin-solidity/test/helpers/expectThrow';
...
}).then(function () {
    return expectThrow(testit.transfer(admin_address,50,{from:admin_address}));
}).then(function () {
...
```

In case you need to actually catch exceptions from contract method calls in your main, non-test JS code with web3js, try this:

```
testit
    .transfer(admin_address,50,{from:admin_address})
    .then(...)
    .catch(function (ex) {...} );
    .then(...);
```

Comment: I have to expect throw in test.js file. this "import {expectThrow} from 'openzeppelin-solidity/test/helpers/expectThrow';
" gave error when I used in test.js. @Utgarda

Comment: Please share that message too ;) But to make it work, you need to have OpenZeppelin files, you can't just import anything from the internet. https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity#install

Comment: i have already installed openzeppelin then imported it's file!! @Utgarda

Comment: And what did it tell you, apart from "Error"? Try it without the curly braces.

Comment: it gave error==> import expectThrow from "./node_modules/openzeppelin-solidity/test/helpers/expectThrow.js";
       ^^^^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier   @Utgarda